# Using AMP scripts or SSJS in custom survey landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, survey

I am trying to use AMP scripts or SSJS in survey custom landing page .But both are not working and only the HTML contents are working.Are the coding functionalities supported in survey landing pages?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: After clarification, the Custom Pages option for a Survey do not support AMPScript or SSJS.

Comment: Hi Mac ,I know they are supported in landing pages but are they supported in survey custom submission landing pages because when i tried there i didn't get any output it just printed the script.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "survey custom submission landing page".  Are you using a landing page that has a survey content area included in it? Where is the custom code being added?

Comment: When we create a survey using default survey option we get an option to create a custom landing page on submitting the survey .I have added the screenshot in the question .

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, those pages do not support scripting.

Comment: Thank for your clarification Mac .Can you give me any suggestions on this question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130420/how-to-create-simple-html-forms-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud-email-templates