# How to create simple HTML forms in Salesforce Marketing cloud email templates?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template, ssjs

I am trying to create a simple form with one or two fields in the email templates.I have created the same before in landing pages and I am not sure we can achieve the same in email templates .**And my code sample is below which throws validation error**.
**Since the code is in email I don't where should I post** any help regarding this will be helpful.

```
%%[
    var @test
    set @test="test survey"
    set @UrlThispg = RequestParameter('PAGEURL')
]%%
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>
           hi welcome:%%=v(@test)=%%,URL is : %%=v(@UrlThispg )=%% 
  </p>
 <form id="formName" action="%%view_email_url%%" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

<input type="text" name="id">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
<script runat="server" type="text/javascript" >
Platform.Load("core", "1");
if (Request.Method == "POST") 
{

}
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error I get during Generate Preview is**

> **An error occurred when attempting to execute a Javascript block. See inner exception for detail. Script:  Platform.Load("core", "1"); if
>   (Request.Method == "POST")  { }
>
> ListID: 22920 Index: 16
>
> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value Line: 3 Char: 16 if
>   (Request.Method == "POST")
>
> {
>   **

Answer (score 1):

The VAWP URL is a personalization string, not an AMPScript variable, so it needs to be referenced differently.

```
%%[
    var @test
    set @test="test survey"
    set @UrlThispg = RequestParameter('PAGEURL')
    set @VAWP = AttributeValue("view_email_url")
]%%
<!-- snip -->
<form id="formName" action="%%=v(@VAWP)=%%" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

or

```
%%[
    var @test
    set @test="test survey"
    set @UrlThispg = RequestParameter('PAGEURL')
]%%
<!-- snip -->
<form id="formName" action="%%view_email_url%%" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

That being said, I'd suggest you look into utilizing the [**_messagecontext**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/) personalization string for determining if the email is being rendered via VAWP or not.

**NOTE:** Also keep in mind that the `view_email_url` is transient -- meaning if you are depending on data in your sending Data Extension, if that data is gone, there's a possibility that your VAWP destination will be broken.

Comment: Hi Adam thanks for your comments. I am using this snippets in Email templates but I am not sure about the value in the "Action" as i don't have access to landing pages  I have just given some tries.Also I have used messagecontext but that doesnt give me any ideas.Any insight on what will be the value for action?When i try generate preview i get error

Comment: I have just updated the  question with the error

Comment: `Request.Method` is only available on landing pages, which is why I suggested you use `_messageContext`.  You need to detect when the code is rendered in an email vs the VAWP.

Comment: Hi Adam I was able to post to VAWP based on the messagecontext but is there a way to access the form field on post as request methods will not be supported in Emails is there any other methods?

Comment: Hi Adam I was able to fix the errors in

Comment: @ManojChandran if Adam's answer is correct, please mark as the correct one..